# About "Some Like It Bot"

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms, headlinese, pun

This [article](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/some-like-it-bot/) has a strange title:

> **Some Like It Bot**
>   Algorithms are getting better at entertaining us.
>
> Artificial intelligence has captured the rhythm of science fiction. For example, the script of a new science fiction short is the creation of a bot. Although the software provides...

What does it mean? What's the logic or pun behind it? It's extremely un-grammatical, but as a title it is acceptable, so I read it like "Some people like it to be a robot", but I'm not sure and wonder if there is more  meaning behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pun on the well-known phrase "some like it hot."

This originates from the nursery rhyme *[Pease Porridge Hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pease_Porridge_Hot).* Wikipedia lists a number of works of art or literature titled "[Some Like It Hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Some_Like_It_Hot_(disambiguation))."

In the nursery rhyme, "some like it hot" refers to people who prefer a certain type of porridge (people who like "hot" porridge). I would interpret "some like it bot" to likewise refer to people who prefer a certain type of something unspecified (people who like "bot" something-or-other). In the case of this article, it seems to mean "some people like 'robotically' generated entertainment."